# Restrict Total number of On Bootstrap toggle switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement number of total enabled services via Bootstrap toggle switch. So I have put Bootstrap toggle switch with each of services provided, but I want to implement in such a way that on a particular time maximum 4 services should be in On mode. After selecting 4 switch to on mode rest of switches should be disabled.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="toggle-event"> Service 1
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="toggle-event"> Service 2
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="toggle-event"> Service 3
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="toggle-event"> Service 4
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="toggle-event"> Service 5
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="toggle-event"> Service 6
```

Visit http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ for bootstrap toggle switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can limit like this:

[https://jsfiddle.net/bhumi/avr803pw/](https://jsfiddle.net/bhumi/avr803pw/1/)

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').bootstrapSwitch();
 var limit = 4;
 $('[type="checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {

  if($('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > limit ) {
   $(this).bootstrapSwitch('state', !state, true);
       alert('You are allowed to check a maximum of '+limit+' options')
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhumi Shah